# \usetikzlibrary{graphs} is not working

Tags: tikz-pgf

```
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}

\tikz \graph { a -> {b, c} -> d };
```

I learn Tikz through { Tikz pgf}. I write above code and compile errors occur. i mention what errors comes.

i write this code after complied errors occured

> Please type another input file name: ^C! I can't find file tikzlibrarygraphs.standard.code.tex'.
>    ...nput tikzlibrary\pgf@temp .code.tex                                                   \catcode `\@ =\csname tikz...
>   l.16 \usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphs.standard}
>                                               (Press Enter to retry, or Control-D to exit)
>   Please type another input file name:

Comment: Put the `\usetiklibrary{graphs}` before `\begin{document}` and compile with LuaLaTeX

Comment: Depending which features are being used, LuaLaTeX may not be needed (though it won't hurt).

Answer (score 2):

If somebody stumbles across this error - for graphdrawing you need

- TikZ version 3.0 or newer
- The `graphdrawing` library (but it should be in the TikZ bundle since 3.0)
- LuaTeX for compiling - make sure that it's used
- Loading `tikz` and `graphdrawing` and, if needed, related libraries, such as:

  ```
  \usepackage{tikz}
  \usetikzlibrary{graphdrawing,graphdrawing.trees,graphs}
  ```